# Diff database dumps, output modifications as working database queries

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say we have a database dump "A" done before some important database changes and a dump "B" done after. Is there a program/script the would take those dumps, diff them and output SQL queries necessary for transforming a database in "A" state into "B" state?

For instance diff results like this:

```
- INSERT INTO table1 (`idx`) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);
+ INSERT INTO table1 (`idx`) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6);
...
- INSERT INTO table2 (`idx`, `txt`) VALUES (1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c');
+ INSERT INTO table2 (`idx`, `txt`) VALUES (1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'x');
```

would results in these SQL queries:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (`idx`) VALUES (6);
UPDATE table2 SET txt = 'x' WHERE idx = 3;
```

I know using it would require caution, but I think it would be useful when some DB changes have to accompany code changes. So, is there such a program?

Comment: Added `mysql` tag due to the usage of the non-standard backtick `\`` for quoting the identifiers